# Specifying transparent cutouts in xml drawable

Tags: android, drawable, transparent, shapes, mask

Does Android support specifying transparent cutouts in XML shape drawables?

NOTE: I'm using Android Studio and targeting API 14+.

I'm trying to create some simple images with a  and several  objects.  But, so far, if I specify a color with an alpha of 0, then I don't see the shape at all.  What I want, is the foreground shape, with an alpha of 0 for the color, to create a transparent area that cuts out the layers below it.

I'd rather not do it in code.

Can anyone show me an example of how to do this?